# Using a read-only replica in synchronous commit mode, is it possible for a query to get different results on the secondary than the primary?

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

I'm using a simple availability group with a primary server and a secondary replica. They are configured like this:

[image]

I have situations where I will insert a row into Table A on the primary using a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableA(UniqueId, Column1)
SELECT 123, Column2
FROM @TVP
```

And after that I immediately query the values from TableA using a read-only connection.

```
SELECT Column1
FROM TableA
WHERE UniqueId = 123
```

Sometimes when making this query, we do not get any rows back. I assume this is because the read-only replica hasn't gotten the data from the primary replica yet but I thought that the insert query would not return until the data had been hardened to the secondary replica.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a synchronous AG replica, the commit is hardened on both the primary and secondary nodes when the `INSERT` transaction commits. However, the changes will not be visible on the secondary until a redo thread on the secondary applies the changes. The latency is typically short but can be delayed due to blocking on high resource utilization on the secondary.

See the [Data Latency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15#DataLatency) topic in the documentation for more information.